# What is a Touch Word™?

Tags: word, pattern, knowledge, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a Touch Word™.

Use the following examples below to find the rule.

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{Touch Words™}&\textbf{Not Touch Words™}\\
\hline
\text{DECOMPOSE}&\text{DECAY}\\
\hline
\text{ENEMY}&\text{LINE}\\
\hline
\text{EXPEDIENCY}&\text{QUEUE}\\
\hline
\text{ESCAPE}&\text{EIGHTY}\\
\hline
\text{DEVIOUS}&\text{TEDIOUS}\\
\hline
\text{IVY}&\text{EXCELLENCY}\\
\hline
\text{FOURSCORE}&\text{UNKNOWN}\\
\hline
\text{BORING}&\text{TRICKY}\\
\hline
\text{EFFICIENCY}&\text{TEENAGER}\\
\hline
\text{FUGITIVE}&\text{EXTRA}\\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Touch Words™,Not Touch Words™
DECOMPOSE,DECAY
ENEMY,LINE
EXPEDIENCY,QUEUE
ESCAPE,EIGHTY
DEVIOUS,TEDIOUS
IVY,EXCELLENCY
FOURSCORE,UNKNOWN
BORING,TRICKY
EFFICIENCY,TEENAGER
FUGITIVE,EXTRA
```

But don't use it.

Thanks to [Engineer Toast](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/9000/engineer-toast) and [GentlePurpleRain](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/4421/gentlepurplerain) for posting all the words I needed [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/24694/what-is-a-sound-word) and [there](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/22992/what-is-a-structurally-sound-word).

Comment: is important the "T" being lower than the rest? :/

Comment: @lois6b I'm not sure to understand your question, but the response is certainly: nope.

Comment: ah ok, i just the font then

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think I got this one right

> While pronouncing(correctly) the word, if your lips 'touch' or if your lip 'touch' your teeth, then it is a touch word

Comment: Damn I'm too slow today Q.Q, I was thinking about the same, just checking it while writing the answer. Nice!

Comment: @Yandrakus twice ninja'd today lol

Comment: @lois6b release all ninjas!

Comment: At least in my case, "Tricky" and "Ivy" would be in the same column by this analysis.

Comment: @abligh Yeah... Being not a native English speaker I might have mispronounced things, sorry. It might also depends where you come from...

Comment: That's why I mentioned correct pronunciation according to the dictionary.
In Ivy, lower lip touches your teeth on letter 'v'

Comment: @Puck , TejasavaDhyani the problem is not the 'v', but the 'r'. At least for most British English speakers (who don't roll their 'r's), an 'r' is pronounced with the top teeth touching the bottom lip, similar to a 'v', but with less breath and quicker. But yes, depends where you are from. The above would work for (e.g.) a native French speaker who would have more attractive 'r' sounds than us Brits.

Comment: @abligh I am not British but We folow UK english and further I've studied phonetics also. Maybe thats why I was able to figure that out correctly. And I think UK english is more clearer ref : http://dictionary.cambridge.org/pronunciation/english/tricky

Comment: Yet with a little ventroloquism it doesn't work!

Comment: @abligh TIL. As an American, I pronounce 'r' without rolling it but also without touching my teeth to my lip.