# What is a Close-knit Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>My first contribution to the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) puzzle series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) over a year ago.</sub>

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a **Close-Knit Word™**.

Use the list of examples below to find out what this rule is.

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{Close-Knit Words™}&\textbf{Not Close-Knit Words™}\\
\hline
\text{EDUCATION}&\text{LEARNING}\\
\hline
\text{FOGHORN}&\text{KLAXON}\\
\hline
\text{ARTISTIC}&\text{IMAGINATIVE}\\
\hline
\text{BOOTSTRAPS}&\text{SHOELACES}\\
\hline
\text{ELIMINATE}&\text{EXTERMINATE}\\
\hline
\text{PONYTAIL}&\text{PLAIT}\\
\hline
\text{HIKING}&\text{WALKING}\\
\hline
\text{REMUNERATION}&\text{RETURN}\\
\hline
\text{FAVOURITE}&\text{BOOKMARK}\\
\hline
\text{BACKDROP}&\text{SCENERY}\\
\hline
\text{FENCED}&\text{PRIVATE}\\
\hline
\text{JAYWALKING}&\text{BURGLARY}\\
\hline
\text{INQUIRIES}&\text{INVESTIGATION}\\
\hline
\text{DISGUSTING}&\text{REVOLTING}\\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

Text-only version for analysis:

```
EDUCATION     LEARNING
FOGHORN       KLAXON
ARTISTIC      IMAGINATIVE
BOOTSTRAPS    SHOELACES
ELIMINATE     EXTERMINATE
PONYTAIL      PLAIT
HIKING        WALKING
REMUNERATION  RETURN
FAVOURITE     BOOKMARK
BACKDROP      SCENERY
FENCED        PRIVATE
JAYWALKING    BURGLARY
INQUIRIES     INVESTIGATION
DISGUSTING    REVOLTING
```

Comment: I copied the table formatting from Puck in [this puzzle](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42175/what-is-a-touch-word). The fact that T's appear smaller than the other letters is irrelevant.

Comment: Whether they do depends on details of your computer and your web browser. E.g., right now for me they don't appear smaller, but on my computer at work they do :-).

Comment: Ah! You don't have the yellow background! UNACCEPTABLE!

Comment: @Mithrandir Umm... he's not Engineer Toast, why should he have them? Anyways, I have the file for these.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think "close-knit words" are

> ones with three consecutive letters of the alphabet in them.

Thus:

> CDE EDUCATION
>  FGH FOGHORN
>  RST ARTISTIC
>  RST BOOTSTRAPS
>  LMN ELIMINATE
>  NOP PONYTAIL
>  GHI HIKING
>  MNO REMUNERATION
>  TUV FAVOURITE
>  ABC BACKDROP
>  DEF FENCED
>  JKL JAYWALKING
>  QRS INQUIRIES
>  STU DISGUSTING

Comment: Jesus, that was fast. Clearly I made this one too easy :-) How did you find the solution?

Comment: @randal'thor For me, I got it as soon as I got down to the word `BACKDROP`.

Comment: @Will Damn, I tried to pick words which wouldn't make it too obvious, avoiding things like 'CAB' and 'STUPID' and 'DEFINITE'. Apparently I failed :-(

Comment: I thought "OK, something to do with some kind of proximity". I started reading the list of Close-Knit words and noticed (I forget) either the ED or the D_C of EDUCATION and thought "hmm, maybe something to do with alphabetically adjacent letters". I read a few more words and it was kinda obvious. Sorry!

Comment: I suspect (but neither my introspection nor my memory is reliable enough to be sure) that ELIMINATE was helpful because the first three *syllables* go EL IM IN :-).

Comment: Too late to answer, but ELIMINATE helped me because it eliminated the notion that the letters had to be consecutive in the word. Then WALKING showed that more than 2 were needed.