# What is a Tight Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a **Tight Word™**.

Use the list of examples below to find out what this rule is.

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{Tight Words™}&\textbf{Not Tight Words™}\\
\hline
\text{NUMEROUS}&\text{MANY}\\
\hline
\text{CONCUR}&\text{AGREE}\\
\hline
\text{NERVOUSNESS}&\text{JUMPINESS}\\
\hline
\text{VERONA}&\text{MANTUA}\\
\hline
\text{WORN}&\text{PATCHED}\\
\hline
\text{MAUVE}&\text{PURPLE}\\
\hline
\text{RAXACORICO}&\text{FALLAPATORIUS}\\
\hline
\text{MENACE}&\text{DENNIS}\\
\hline
\text{ROME}&\text{ITALY}\\
\hline
\text{NICENESS}&\text{KINDNESS}\\
\hline
\text{VIEWS}&\text{PANORAMA}\\
\hline
\text{CURVACEOUS}&\text{ROUNDED}\\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

Text-only version for analysis:

```
NUMEROUS      MANY
CONCUR        AGREE
NERVOUSNESS   JUMPINESS
VERONA        MANTUA
WORN          PATCHED
MAUVE         PURPLE
RAXACORICO    FALLAPATORIUS
MENACE        DENNIS
ROME          ITALY
NICENESS      KINDNESS
VIEWS         PANORAMA
CURVACEOUS    ROUNDED
```

Comment: I copied the table formatting from [my previous word-property puzzle](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/42209/5373). The fact that T's appear smaller than the other letters is irrelevant.

Comment: @Will Oops, sorry! I changed my idea for this puzzle halfway through making it. There may be a Well-Knit puzzle in the future, if I can find enough Well-Knit Words, but this one is Tight.

Comment: Does the font matter in any way?

Comment: @Peanut Nope, I don't think so.

Comment: I'm probably trying to make it connect with "Tight Words™" too much. I'm going to ignore that and find other connections.

Comment: I'm guessing  that `PLY`  is well-knit, in-fact it is the only word I could find in it's class.

Comment: [This.](http://www.reactiongifs.us/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/tight_tight_tight_breaking_bad.gif)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A **Tight Word™**

> contains only letters without ascenders or descenders in lowercase. That is, it contains **a c e i m n o r s u v w x z**, but doesn't contain **b d f h k l t**, which extend above the midline, or **g j p q y**, which extend below the baseline.